# MS SQL SERVER 2014: Get Number of Days Between Occurrences

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with the following structure (Occurrence Table):

```
ID    EmployeeID      DateOfOccurrence
--------------------------------------
1     999999          2017-02-14
2     999999          2017-03-02
3     999999          2017-03-23
4     999999          2017-05-10
```

I would like to create a query to return the result (grouped by employeeid):

```
999999     2017-02-14 to 2017-03-02     16 days
999999     2017-03-02 to 2017-03-23     21 days
999999     2017-03-23 to 2017-05-10     48 days
999999     2017-05-10 to <today>        xx days 

* <today> = current day (i.e., getdate())
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: are your dates always sequential (ordered by ID)

Comment: No they are not. There could be gaps between occurrences for an employee. Occurrences are added each morning for all employees (if they have one).

Comment: why is the first row 16 days, but the second row 20 days (instead of 21)?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `concat()`, `lead()`, `isnull()`, and `datediff()`:

```
select 
    id
  , range = concat(
      convert(char(10),dateofoccurence,120)
    , ' to '
    , convert(char(10),isnull(lead(dateofoccurence) over (partition by employeeid order by dateofoccurence),getdate()),120)
  )
  , days = concat(
      datediff(
         day
       , dateofoccurence
       , isnull(lead(dateofoccurence) over (partition by employeeid order by dateofoccurence),getdate())
      )
    , ' days')
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FNQ48539

returns:

```
+----+--------------------------+---------+
| id |          range           |  days   |
+----+--------------------------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-02-14 to 2017-03-02 | 16 days |
|  2 | 2017-03-02 to 2017-03-23 | 21 days |
|  3 | 2017-03-23 to 2017-05-10 | 48 days |
|  4 | 2017-05-10 to 2017-05-24 | 14 days |
+----+--------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY. Thank you so much.

Comment: And you applauded my deciphering skillz... your's are better +1

Comment: @scsimon deciphering wasn't really necessary since desired results were provided, but thanks!

Comment: @klbass68 You are going to have to explain what you mean for me to be able to respond in any meaningful way.

Comment: @SqlZim Is there a way to use over partition with a date range?

Comment: @SqlZim When I add the following where clause to the query you provided it still returns ALL dates. Not just those between:

dateofoccurrence between '01-01-2017' and '04-03-2017 23:59:59.999'

Comment: @klbass68 that conflicts with the `... to <today>` part of your question. If you want to have a predefined end date instead of `<today>` then you can use parameters like so: http://rextester.com/SHHT77390

Comment: @SqlZim DUH! Sorry to bother you. Thanks again.